# Horizontal and vertical scrolling on a + shaped website

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

Currently I am working on a site I am having quite a few difficulties with. Basically, I am trying to make a site in a + shape, which should feature a bi-directional scrolling system. I am trying to make the site look like this:

E C E
C C C
E C E

Where E is empty, non-viewable space. And C is an actual div, with content in it. All content divs will have links to eachother, so the user can visit other parts of the site.

Because my jQuery and JavaScript isn't the best, I've had a lot of trouble to get the site to scroll around on a link-click-action. I finally managed to get it to work with the jQuery scrollTo library, though now I have a different problem. A user is now still able to scroll to the 'empty' parts of the website, which is a big usability problem. I tried closing this empty space off, by using overflow:hidden, yet this breaks the entire scroll system. At the same time, I would also like the middle content div to show up first, on entering of the site (box5). But because my jQuery/Javascript skills are currently extremely crappy, I am having a lot of trouble to get this site to work.

Any help, or nudging in a right direction would be much appreciated!

Here is my current work:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!--<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <!-- Load jQuery (newer versions will not work) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load ScrollTo -->
    <script src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load LocalScroll -->
    <script src="http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Link Scrolling-->
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="box-links">
<!-- Temporary table as site reference -->
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>(Empty)</a></td>
    <td><a href="#box2" class="box2link">box2 (News)</a></td>
    <td>(Empty)</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#box4" class="box4link">box4 (Day 1)</a></td>
    <td><a href="#box5" class="box5link">box5 (Home/Index)</a></td>
    <td><a href="#box6" class="box6link">box6 (Day 2)</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>(Empty)</td>
    <td><a href="#box8" class="box8link">box8 (Unspecified)</a></td>
    <td>(Empty)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div><!-- end box-links-->

<div id="master_container">

<div id="box2" class="container">
</div>

<div id="box4" class="container">
</div>
<div id="box5" class="container">
</div>
<div id="box6" class="container">
</div>

<div id="box8" class="container">
</div>

</div> <!-- end master container-->

<footer>

</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* Temporary placement of reset.css */

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

/*table, tr, th, td, tijdelijk uitgehaald */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, 
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*====================================================================================*/







html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


#master_container{
    width:300%;
    height:300%;
    min-width:3000px;

}

.container{
    width: 33.2%;
    height: 33.3%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #0CF;
    border: 2px dashed #000;
}

    #box2, #box8{
        margin: 0 33.3% 0 33.3%;
    }

footer{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#F00;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

init.js

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    /**
     * Most jQuery.localScroll's settings, actually belong to jQuery.ScrollTo, check it's demo for an example of each option.
     * @see http://flesler.demos.com/jquery/scrollTo/
     * You can use EVERY single setting of jQuery.ScrollTo, in the settings hash you send to jQuery.LocalScroll.
     */

    // The default axis is 'y', but in this demo, I want to scroll both
    // You can modify any default like this
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
    // When the document is loaded...
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // Scroll the whole document
        $('#box-links').localScroll({
           target:'body',
            queue:true,
            duration:1000,
            hash:true,
            onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
                // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
            },
            onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
                // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
            }

        });


    });
});
```

Please excuse me if I did not place the code correctly here.

Comment: So you basically want a single page website

Comment: Search for 'single page website' and you might find what you are searching for.

Comment: I have looked at single page websites, that's how I found out about the scrollTo Library. Most single page websites don't do vertical AND horizontal scrolling though. At least, I am finding it a hard time to find tutorials on that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea yesterday and managed to figure it out. My example uses the scrollTo plugin and some simple jquery animations. This can probably be cleaned up a bit, but it's a start.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz5YF/17/)

The HTML

```
<section class="right">
        <h1>Right</h1>
        <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-left">Left</a></h2>
</section>

<section class="left">
     <h1>Left</h1>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-right">Right</a></h2>
</section>

<section class="middle">
     <h1>Home/middle</h1>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-up">up</a></h2>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-down">down</a></h2>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-left">Left</a></h2>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-right">Right</a></h2>
</section>

<section class="top">
     <h1>Top</h1>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-down">down</a></h2>
</section>

<section class="bottom">
     <h1>Bottom</h1>
     <h2><a href="#" class="toggle-up">up</a></h2>
</section>
```

The jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('html').scrollTo('+=' + width, 0, {
        axis: 'x'
    })

    //left & right section
    $(".toggle-right").click(function () {
        $('html').scrollTo('+=' + width, 800, {
            axis: 'x'
        });
    });
    $(".toggle-left").click(function () {
        $('html').scrollTo('-=' + width, 800, {
            axis: 'x'
        });
    });

    //top section
    $(".top .toggle-down").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.top').animate({
            top: "-100%",
        }, 800);
        $('.middle').animate({
            top: "0",
        }, 800);
    });

    //middle section
    $(".middle .toggle-up").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.top').animate({
            top: "0",
        }, 800);
        $('.middle').animate({
            top: "100%",
        }, 800);
    });
    $(".middle .toggle-down").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.bottom').animate({
            bottom: "0",
        }, 800);
        $('.middle').animate({
            top: "-100%",
        }, 800);
    });

    //bottom section
    $(".bottom .toggle-up").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.bottom').animate({
            bottom: "-100%",
        }, 800);
        $('.middle').animate({
            top: "0",
        }, 800);
    });

});
```

The CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
body {
    font: 20px/21px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    height:100%;
}
a {
    color: #e74b34;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #132c3b;
    text-decoration:none;
}
section {
    height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.top {
    background: #111;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left: 100%;
    top:-100%;
}
.bottom {
    background: #111;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left: 100%;
    bottom:-100%;
    background: #ccc;
}
.middle {
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
}
.right {
    background: #111;
    position:absolute;
    left:200%;
    top:0;
}
```